# How to groupby column and return a dataFrame instead of groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame that looks as such:

```
Date        Yearly_cost
2009-01-01  230
2010-03-03  260
2009-01-01  320
2007-03-02  430
```

The same dataFrame contains multiple duplicate values for Date but different values for Yearly_cost. I want to groupby Date so that I have a consistent time series with all corresponding values for each day. However I want it to return a df rather than a groupby object.

The desired result would look as such:

`Date        Yearly_cost
    2007-03-02  430
    2009-01-01  230, 320
    2010-03-03  260`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you not join the dfs?

Comment: Please give an example of what `df2` looks like - and what your end result should look like

Comment: Apologies m I got muddled up doing two things at work. I only have one df with multiple values for date column with different corresponding values for `Yearly_cost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the revised question, use:

```
df.groupby('Date')['Yearly_cost'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Yearly_cost')
```

If you want to change e.g. `[320]` to `320`, do:

```
df.groupby('Date')['Yearly_cost'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x).reset_index(name='Yearly_cost')
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2009-01-01', '2009-01-01', '2010-03-03' , '2010-03-03', '2004-04-03' ,'2007-03-02'],
'Yearly_cost': [230 ,460, 260, 250, 320 ,430],})
df1
```

df1

```
        Date    Yearly_cost
0   2009-01-01  230
1   2009-01-01  460
2   2010-03-03  260
3   2010-03-03  250
4   2004-04-03  320
5   2007-03-02  430
```

You can do the following:

```
df1['Yearly_cost'] = df1.Yearly_cost.astype(str)
df1.groupby('Date')['Yearly_cost'].apply(','.join)
```

Result:

```
Date
2004-04-03        320
2007-03-02        430
2009-01-01    230,460
2010-03-03    260,250
Name: Yearly_cost, dtype: object
```

In order to make the above a dataframe:

```
df1['Yearly_cost'] = df1.Yearly_cost.astype(str)
combined = df1.groupby('Date')['Yearly_cost'].apply(','.join)
pd.DataFrame(combined)
```

And you'll get:

```
            Yearly_cost
Date    
2004-04-03  320
2007-03-02  430
2009-01-01  230,460
2010-03-03  260,250
```

Comment: Apologies it's my fault, I got the question wrong, I was trying to do two things at once at work.

Comment: There is only 1 df with multiple values for Date. I wish to have singular values for `date` whilst having all values for Yearly_cost on that day.

Comment: @geds133 Might be worthed to look at my answer

Comment: the problem with the above solution is that the column `Yearly_cost` has an object type, but I guess you can get around it. Check the Edit anyway